# Row color as a command with a counter and if-else statement

Tags: tables, color, counters, rowcolor

I am making a table and I want to colorize odd and even rows in different colors. I made a new command with a counter. The counter is being incremented with each new row and the if-else statement switches between the two colors. When I use the command, it is an error while processing my file. The error is `! Misplaced \noalign`. I look at the command and have no idea what is wrong. Help me please to find the mistake.

```
\newcounter{irow}
\setcounter{irow}{0}
\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{HTML}{f7f5f5}
\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{HTML}{87e09f}
\newcommand{\ColorizeRow}{\addtocounter{irow}{1}\ifodd\value{irow}\rowcolor{oddrowcolor}\else\rowcolor{evenrowcolor}\fi}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \ColorizeRow
  A & B & C \\
  \ColorizeRow
  D & E & F\\
  \ColorizeRow
  G & H & I \\
  \ColorizeRow
  J & K & L \\
  \ColorizeRow
  M & N & O \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\rowcolor` of `colortbl` begins with `\noalign` and we must put only expandable material (in the TeX meaning) before a `\noalign`. The instruction `\addtocounter{irow}{1}` is not expandable (as all the instructions of affectation).

However, you can put `\addtocounter{irow}{1}` after the instruction `\rowcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,array,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{irow}
\setcounter{irow}{0}
\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{HTML}{f7f5f5}
\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{HTML}{87e09f}
\newcommand{\ColorizeRow}{\ifodd\value{irow}\rowcolor{evenrowcolor}\else\rowcolor{oddrowcolor}\fi \addtocounter{irow}{1}}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \ColorizeRow
  A & B & C \\
  \ColorizeRow
  D & E & F\\
  \ColorizeRow
  G & H & I \\
  \ColorizeRow
  J & K & L \\
  \ColorizeRow
  M & N & O \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you very much. I should read more about the expandable stuff. I heard about it but don't understand for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why you like to invent something what already exist. Package `xcolor` has option `table` for coloring tables. This option define (among others):

```
\rowcolors{<row num>}{<odd color>}{<even color>}
```

where `row num` is number of row, where this command is activated. For example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
\rowcolors{1}{red}{blue}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
A & B & C \\
  D & E & F \\
  G & H & I \\
  J & K & L \\
  M & N & O \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
\rowcolors{2}{red}{blue}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
A & B & C \\
  D & E & F \\
  G & H & I \\
  J & K & L \\
  M & N & O \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[!htb]
\rowcolors{1}{}{blue}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
A & B & C \\
  D & E & F \\
  G & H & I \\
  J & K & L \\
  M & N & O \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you like to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to colorize rows like this. I did not know the command ```\rowcolor``` has such an ability with even and odd rows. So I started to make my own command. Thank you, I will add it to my file. Of course, it's better to use what is already realized.

Comment: @Vladimir, if you would google for *table coloring*, you would find plenty solution how to do this. For example, some packages, as is `tabularray` has integrated table coloring. Anyway, I would drop your approach and use reliable solutions tested thousands times ...

Comment: Completely agree about changing the approach, thank you.

Comment: @Vladimir: The package `nicematrix`  also provides tools for coloring of tables...